# Is there a function to Extract the day name From Table in Big Query?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I Tried different functions all of them need to write the date manually like this SELECT DAYNAME("2017-06-15");

i need that from a table ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%A', "2017-06-15")
```

with output

[image]

> But i need to extract day name from A column Calls Activity Day inside a table

use your column name instead of constant - like in below

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%A', col_name)
FROM your_table
```

See more about [FORMAT_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date)

Comment: Thank you But i need to extract day name from A column Calls Activity Day inside a table